# how to get std::class array value

Tags: php

```
array (
  'subdomain' => 'ioio',
  'sub_user' => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'id' => 7,
  )),
)
```

Hi, i'm trying to get the sub_user `id`. I did try something like `$sub_user[0]->id` but the structure doesn't have key with 0.

Comment: `$sub_user->id` then?

Comment: try `$sub_user->__set_state[0]->id`

Comment: `$yourArray['sub_user']->__set_state['id']` should give you `7`, if that is an array with a Standard Class at `sub_user` that has a `__set_state` property that's an associative array with an `id` property.

Comment: nope...all getting Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: What is that, your `print_r()`?

Comment: Is your code is the output of a var_export? Could you post your actual array?

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it as an array:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->foo = 'foo';
$a->bar = 'bar';

$arrayOfA = get_object_vars($a);
print_r($arrayOfA);
// Casting ((array)$a) also works
```